# Pex still good in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: microsoft-fakes, moles, pex, pex-and-moles

I use Visual Studio Community 2015 and would like to know if I can still set up Pex and moles framework as I would have in VS 2013, for use with my community VS 2015, since I do not have the new intelligent feature.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that it is not available. You could [`vote here`](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/2216195-include-pex-and-moles-with-all-visual-studio-editi) for it being available in all VS 2015 editions and not restricted to Premium and Ultimate editions.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I intend to vote for it